# React hashRouter doesn't render correct component when refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-v4

I'm trying to implement the React HashRouter from react-router-v4... It works perfectly when I navigate over the page when using all the buttons...

But on a Page refresh I get a strange behavior. May someone of you can help me. Here's my code:

```
 <HashRouter basename='/app'>
     <Route component={App} />
 </HashRouter>
```

And then, my Router:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/statistics' component={Statistics}/>
    <Route path='/search' component={Search}/>
    <Route path='/settings' component={User}/>
    <Route path='/demo' component={Demo}/>
    <Route path='/' component={Statistics}/>
    <Route render={() => <SiteNotFound />} />
</Switch>
```

Whenever I reload the page, the "Statistics" component get rendered, because the http://localhost:8080/#/app/demo I expect the Demo component to be rendered, but I get the Statistics Component.
Can someone explain me this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this `<Route path='/' exact component={Statistics}/>`

Comment: I tried, but then the "SiteNotFound" componnent gets rendered all the time.